# Automatically creating & deploying a separate dashboard for each customer

Tags: shiny, automation, data-visualization, dashboard, multiple-instances

I am working on a use-case where the product is subscription based and each new customer who signs in will have a unique dashboard displayed to them based on the algorithm output from the product. I have process automated till getting different results for each customer but my question is which tool can get me a unique dashboard for each customer on which I may plot the outputs I have generated? This will be the last part of my automated pipeline.

I would like all these dashboards on one server because if this product scales to 1000 customers, having 1000 servers running will be infeasible.

I am used to working on R Shiny but I couldn't see any links where you can do this easily i.e. deploy multiple apps on the same shiny server and just get a separate URL for each. Which other tools can I explore? Or can I implement the above process in Shiny itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use an app where the user has to sign in, you could make one Shiny app and show the content depending on who signed in. If you don't want a login, maybe you can work with cookies and load different content based on the cookie information?

Comment: Yes the app requests the user to sign in. How do I set it up in such a way that the appropriate content will be shown depending on who signs in?